# Watchdog test binary: "Operation not permitted"

Tags: bash, shell-script, permissions, process, watchdog

I use one of my computers only as a remote-controlled device. Sometimes it gets into a weird state in which it doesn't respond to AnyDesk anymore and doesn't show anything if I connect a screen. I couldn't yet figure out why this happens, but for now I wanted to just let it restart in those cases and in any other problematic case that might happen. I decided that if AnyDesk is running, it should be fine (or I can add an additional network check later).
So I set up `/etc/watchdog.conf` like this (commented lines not included here):

```
watchdog-timeout        = 600
realtime                = yes
priority                = 1
retry-timeout           = 600
repair-maximum          = 1
test-directory = /etc/watchdog.d
```

And a file `/etc/watchdog.d/anydesk_running.sh` exists with this content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
pgrep -x "anydesk"
```

That file has all the permissions it could ever want (and for sure it's readable and executable by root), but I get this message in the system log anyway, every second (not even just every 10 minutes):

`watchdog[621]: test binary /etc/watchdog.d/anydesk_running.sh returned 1 = 'Operation not permitted'`

`pgrep` doesn't even require root permissions and the watchdog does run as root, so I don't see why that should be an issue. Executing the file also shouldn't be an issue. But then what is? All documentation says "test **binary**", not "test **script**", but I've seen some mentions of .sh files being used there, so I would assume that that works as well.

**Why does watchdog not like my script and how do I fix this permission issue?**

Comment: Doesn't this mean `pgrep -x "anydesk"` is not finding that process, so returning exit code 1 (==EPERM, Op not permitted).

Comment: That's a pretty bad error message then. But yes, that command does return 1 if it can't find a process. But then why doesn't watchdog restart the computer? And why does it try again every second instead of every 10 minutes? I've edited the script to `if [ "$1" == "1" ]; then reboot; else pgrep -x "anydesk"; done` now, let's see if that helps. There's something in the documentation about it calling the script with the exit code as argument again, maybe that's INSTEAD of a reboot.

Comment: Now it's rebooting all the time, even while I'm actively remote-controlling it with Anydesk in that moment.

Comment: I have now tried a lot more thinga, including implementing my own failure counter and reboot command inside that script, but it always kept rebooting when it shouldn't. so I removed the reboot command from my script completely, but it kept rebooting. So I commented out every line of the script, but it kept rebooting. So I commented out the "test-directory" line, but it kept rebooting. I had to completely stop and disable the watchdog to make that stop. I'm beginning to think that the watchdog in general is useless and completely broken and I should just run my own script on a loop instead.